# postgres and a big list of IPv6 address

Tags: postgresql

I have about 6000 IPv6 addresses I need loaded into a postgres table. without even getting to the point of finding my 'if not exist error' it borks on the unescaped ':'
I don't know postgres that well, is there a LOAD DATA INFILE function that will read in the lines and ignore the ':' as well as look for existing records?

```
INSERT INTO ip_list (ip_addr)
SELECT 'ip_addr',
 2600:3c01:e000:44:0:0:0:1,
 2600:3c01:e000:44:0:0:0:2,
 2600:3c01:e000:44:0:0:0:3,
 2600:3c01:e000:44:0:0:0:4,
 2600:3c01:e000:44:0:0:0:5,
 2600:3c01:e000:44:0:0:0:7,
....
WHERE NOT EXIST(
        SELECT 1 FROM ip_list WHERE name = 'ip_addr')
        RETURNING id
        );


ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 3:  2600:3c01:e000:44:0:0:0:1,
```

---

Update:

This method never uploads any records:

```
You are now connected to database "postfix" as user "postgres".
postfix=# create temporary table t(ip_addr inet);
CREATE TABLE
postfix=# \copy t from '/var/www/localhost/htdocs/ipListScript'
postfix=# INSERT INTO ip_list(ip_addr)
select ip_addr from ip_list where
not exists (select 1 from ip_list where ip_list.ip_addr=ip_list.ip_addr);
```

Comment: RE(update) Maybe you are connected to the wrong database? BTW: I am missing the diagnostic `COPY xxx yyy` from your output.

Comment: You are selecting from the same table where not exists (select from the same table). What would you expect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6000 addresses as constants in an SQL statement is unreasonable, besides your proposed syntax being incorrect anyway (a `VALUES` clause would be needed).

The reasonable way is to `COPY` into a temporary table from the file, and then insert from the temporary table to your final table, eliminating duplicates at the same time.

In psql:

```
create temporary table t(ip_addr inet);

\copy t from '/path/to/file.txt'

INSERT INTO ip_list(ip_addr) 
 select ip_addr from t where
   not exists (select 1 from ip_list where ip_list.ip_addr=t.ip_addr);
```

The `\copy` is a command of the `psql` program that takes care of loading the file client-side and feeding it to the server.

If the context does not allow using the `psql` command, you may use the SQL statement `COPY tablename FROM '/path/to/file.txt'` but then you must be connected as superuser, and the file should be accessible on the server by the `postgres` user.
If these restrictions are not acceptable you want to use `COPY tablename FROM STDIN` and feed the data by your own means.

Comment: why does he need a `VALUES` clause ? `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` is perfectly valid SQL. Not in the way the OP wants to use it of course but still valid SQL as long as the `SELECT` matches the expected columns of `ip_list` in this case.

Comment: @bhs: `insert into.. select from...` is OK, but select from what?

Comment: @bhs: the select as shown in the question, selects a single row with multiple *columns*. It does **not** generate multiple rows.

Comment: I did specify in my comment that the way the OP was using it was wrong. My comment was that saying that the OP needed to use a values clause was wrong. Your answer Daniel gives the impression that the query requires a values clause.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need to put quotes around your IP addresses.  Check out this pages for more info:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-net-types.html

Comment: While the missing quotes is the first error, the second error is that the `select` statement to provide the values is wrong. It is creating a single row with many columns.

Comment: @Daniel Vérité    no records make it.   INSERT 0 0